# Combobox with strong typed items

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I want to create a control that inherits from ComboBox. I want a combobox which only accepts items of a certain type.

So I need to overrule the Items property. (Notice the new keyword).
But what do I put in the set region of this overruled Items property?

```
    new public List<TimeSpanItemClass> Items
    {
        get
        {
            return base.Items.Cast<TimeSpanItemClass>().ToList();
        }
        set
        {
            ?
        }
    }
```

I can't figure it out, and searching on Google yields close to nothing.

Comment: `ComboBox` itself doesn't support `set` on `Items`. Why do you need it?

Comment: Can't you just iterate over the list in the setter and add them to the combo box, or am I missing something?

Comment: Maybe you're misinformed; properties don't _need_ to specify _both_ a `get` and a `set`. You can declare only one if you wish.

Comment: I think that you are going about this the hard way..the easiest way in my opinion would be to create a List<T> of `Class or Specific DataType` and `Bind that List` to the Combobox` unless I am not reading your question properly.. another way would be to create a `Class` for example `public class TimeSpanItemEx<T>: System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox{
}`

Answer (score 4):

The combobox already supports this.

Put your list of elements into the property `DataSource`:

```
var persons = new List<Person>();
// ToDo: fill list with some values...

myComboBox.DataSource = persons;
```

Enter into the property `DisplayMember` the property of the object that will represent what the user should see. If you don't set it, the combo box will call `.ToString()` on the selected element.

```
myComboBox.DisplayMember = "FullName";
```

Enter into the property `ValueMember` the property you like to receive from object in code. If you don't set it, the combo box will return the object itself.

```
myComboBox.ValueMember = "Born";
```

To get the currently selected object out of the combobox simply cast the property `SelectedValue` to the desired type.

```
private void OnComboBoxFormatSelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DateTime born = (DateTime)comboBox.SelectedValue
}
```

#### Update for altering list after assignment

If you need to alter the list or one if its items **after** you have assigned the data source to the combo box you have to inform the combo box about this change. The most trivial way is to simply re-assign the data source to the combo box:

```
myComboBox.DataSource = persons;
```

A more cleaner way would be if the list itself could fire up an event if any change had happened. This feature is implemented by the [`BindingList<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132679.aspx) and let the combo box automatically be updated if you alter the list by adding or removing an element from it.

The next step of information flow would be to inform the combo box if an item itself has been changed (in our example e.g. the last name of a person). To accomplish this your objects within the list have either to implement a `PropertyNameChanged` event (in our example this would be LastNameChanged cause the property name would be LastName) or you have to implement the [`INotifyPropertyChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx) within your class. If you did this and you use a binding list, these events will automatically be forwarded to the combo box and the value will be updated there too.

**Caution**: In the first step the usage of a `BindingList` and `NotifyPropertyChanged` works quite good, but you can really get into trouble if you are going to change the list or an object property out of another thread (leads to Cross-Thread-Exceptions). But it is also possible to avoid this.

You simply need another layer between your ComboBox and the BindingList; a [`BindingSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.aspx). This has the ability to suspend and resume the notification chain, so that you can alter the list from another thread:

```
var persons = new BindingList<Person>();
var bindingSource = new BindingSource();
bindingSource.DataSource = persons;
comboBox.DataSource = bindingSource;

// Suspend change the list from another thread,
// and resume on the gui thread.
bindingSource.SuspendBinding();
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => persons.Add(Person.GetRandomFromDatabase()))
            .ContinueWith(finishedTask => bindingSource.ResumeBinding(),
                            TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
```

Comment: `+1` Much Cleaner answer, once again one of the many ways to skin that `cat`

Comment: I can only get this to work whenever I set the `CustomCombbox.DataSource = List<T>();` after I populated the `List<T>();` But when I set this.DataSource = this.Items in the constructor of CustomCombobox, and add items later on, the items do not show.

Comment: So now I have this `this.cbtsSelectPresetPeriod.Items.Add(TimeSpan.FromDays(2 * 7));
            this.cbtsSelectPresetPeriod.Items.Add(TimeSpan.FromDays(4 * 7));
            this.cbtsSelectPresetPeriod.Items.Add(TimeSpan.FromDays(8 * 7));
            this.cbtsSelectPresetPeriod.Items.Add(TimeSpan.FromDays(16 * 7));
            
            this.cbtsSelectPresetPeriod.DataSource = this.cbtsSelectPresetPeriod.Items;
            this.cbtsSelectPresetPeriod.Items.Add(TimeSpan.FromDays(32 * 7));` But the fifth value is not showing. Why?

Answer (score 0):

```
set {
    throw new NotImplementedException("I don't know why I put a setter here, because it doesn't really make sense");
}
```

Comment: How would I get items into the Item property then. When I put the custom combobox on a form. The designer.cs calls customcombobox.Items = null; And your answer is not really an answer, hence it isn't that helpful.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @MikedeKlerk You don't need a setter. You don't have a physical list, you are pulling the list from the base Items list. To add items to it, add them to the base Items list.

Comment: @SztupY If he insists on having a setter, this is the only possible implementation that makes sense.

Comment: @MikeCaron Did you ever had a physical list while programming :D mine are always in memory. I am curious about the computer and language you use to processes physical lists :P .

Answer (score 0):

I have achieved what I wanted:

1. Creating a custom Combobox control that only allows to add TimeSpan values
2. Show the time span values with a custom format.

It might seem useless to go all the way of creating a custom combobox only accepting one type. But I need this in a big project where comboboxes with timespan values are used often. So keeping all whats necessary in one place (one class, one file) is most convenient.

By using a BindingList (never used it before). This is my code.

```
public partial class ComboBoxTimeSpan : ComboBox
{
    private BindingList<TimeSpanItemClass> _BindingList = new BindingList<TimeSpanItemClass>();

    public ComboBoxTimeSpan()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Items = new BindingList<TimeSpan>();
        this.Items.ListChanged += Items_ListChanged;
        this.DataSource = _BindingList;
    }

    void Items_ListChanged(object sender, ListChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        _BindingList.Clear();
        foreach (TimeSpan ts in Items)
        {
            _BindingList.Add(new TimeSpanItemClass(ts));
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// The items in this combobox need to be of the type TimeSpan as this combobox is designed for showing time span values in easy to read text.
    /// </summary>
    new public BindingList<TimeSpan> Items
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// The ComboBoxTimeSpan has items that can all be converted to a time span.
    /// They will display as 1 hour, 2 hours, 1 minute, 1 hour and 2 minutes, 1 day, 2 weeks and 3 days, 3 days, etc...
    /// Its precise on the microsecond, no less
    /// </summary>
    private class TimeSpanItemClass : Object
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The timespan that this object represents
        /// </summary>
        public TimeSpan timespan
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// The constructor of this class needs a TimeSpan object
        /// </summary>
        public TimeSpanItemClass(TimeSpan ts)
        {
            timespan = ts;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// The textual represention of the time span that this object represents.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>A string by a simple format</returns>
        public override string ToString()
        {
            //Specify your custom format here
            return timespan.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Now the combobox can be used as

```
cbts = new ComboBoxTimeSpan();
ctbs.Add(TimeSpan.FromDays(1));
```

Thanks for all the help!